# In an XML/XSD schema file, how can we extract (parse) certain information from an element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd, xml-parsing

Is there a way of parsing certain data from an XML file, and outputting that information onto an excel(csv) file?

Comment: Can you post sample of xml.  You posted a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. You need to convert xmldocument to xdocument. So you can easily capture each element and its data. I used the same file you provided. I also mentioned example of how to read elements in loop and its child.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parse();
    }

    public static void Parse()
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\New Text Document.xsd");

        var captureElements = new List<CustomElements>();


        var xdocument = xmlDoc.ToXDocument();
        foreach (var element in xdocument.Elements())
        {
            foreach (var node in element.Elements()) //childs...
            {

                if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("ElementType"))
                {
                    foreach (var scopeNode in node.Elements())
                    {
                        if (scopeNode.Name.LocalName.Equals("element"))
                        {
                            var xml = XElement.Parse(scopeNode.ToString());
                            var customElement = new CustomElements();

                            customElement.Type = xml.Attribute("type")?.Value;
                            customElement.Label = xml.Attribute("label")?.Value;
                            customElement.CompTypes = xml.Attribute("CompTypes")?.Value;
                            customElement.Readonly = xml.Attribute("readonly")?.Value;
                            customElement.Hidden = xml.Attribute("hidden")?.Value;
                            customElement.Require = xml.Attribute("require")?.Value;

                            captureElements.Add(customElement);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static class DocumentExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
        {
            nodeReader.MoveToContent();
            return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
        }
    }
}
public class CustomElements
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string CompTypes { get; set; }
    public string Readonly { get; set; }
    public string Hidden { get; set; }
    public string Require { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Saif, thanks for your help, I will give this a try.

Comment: Hi @Saif, in the code that you shown, I was wondering where exactly would I specify the element: type, label, CompTypes, readonly, hidden, require that I want to be displayed for each element?

Comment: Hi @samuel i have update the code above. Please try this one

Comment: Hi @Saif, I made typo in my question. This file is actually schema.xml not schema.xsd. But I think the same steps can be applied since .xsd is an .xml file. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your steps, but it still doesn’t give what I want. I just want only the following data: (type, label, CompTypes, readonly, hidden, require ) for each element.

Comment: @samuel code updated. Please try this one. I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Saif, I have a follow up question based on your code. I am following your steps, and  I was wondering, after getting the data for each element: Type, label, CompTypes, readonly, hidden, required.. where are you storing/outputting the data?  I want to output the data onto a CSV file. For example output the  Type, label, CompTypes, readonly, hidden, required and its values. Could you please demo how to output to a CSV file with the current code? Thanks.

Comment: string csv = String.Join(",", captureElements.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); ..captureElements is the list in which i saved all the collected values in the above example.  You can save the csv string to a file

Comment: If you don’t mind, could you please show, how to output the data to a CSV file using your code above. Do we use streamwritter? I don’t have much exposure  on writing to CSV.

Comment: just use this ..System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\file.txt", csvString);  . Get csvString from above code.

Answer (score 0):

Very easily done in XSLT. You don't need the schema. Unless there are special characters that need to be escaped, etc, it's as simple as:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>  
<xsl:template match="Element"
>{@type},{@label},{@CompTypes},{@readonly},{@hidden},{@required}
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That's an XSLT 3.0 solution; if you prefer to use the XSLT 1.0 processor that comes bundled with .NET that's a bit more verbose but still quite straightforward. I haven't included a header line but it's a simple matter to add it.

In XSLT 3.0 you can even add the automation to apply this to a whole collection of XML files (in 1.0 you would need to do that in a calling script).

Comment: Hi @Michael, that's interesting, I may still want to to use the schema, but I will take a look at your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, use System.Xml.XmlDocument, and XPath syntax in SelectNodes

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load( strFile );
foreach (XmlElement ndRow in xml.SelectNodes("//element")) {
    string strType = ndRow.GetAttribute("type");
    string strLabel = ndRow.GetAttribute("label");
}
```